# Change the order of table column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Well, its probably not bit easy anymore still here it comes.

I want to order the column with table content in Excel in specific order.

i.e I want all the columns with Prefix `('Product'/'product')` to come at end in alphabetical order except 'Product_ID' to be first among them and everything else remains the same.

i.e **Demo**

> **Cust_ID | Name | Product_Quantity | product_Name| Product_ID | Price_per_quantity**
>
> 1 | Rohit | 4 | Pen | A23 | $2
>
> 2 | Tim | 3 | Pot | P41 | $3

to

> **Cust_ID | Name | Price_per_quanity | Product_id | product_Name | Product_Quantity**
>
> 1 | Rohit | $2 | A23...(respective columns data)

I wish to have a generalized way for `n` columns (with/without) **using VBA** script which contains more columns.

Also (2nd question) To reverse the columns irrespective of there value which is solved by fellow SO members.

Comment: This is just a demo , what if Columns are `Product_ID | Cust ID | Name | Product_Name`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `a` is in A1, insert a row at the top and populate with:

```
=COLUMN()
```

copied across above all populated columns. Select all populated columns and sort by Row1 Largest to Smallest.

Comment: Your answer, if correct, is simpler than any other given.  But how can one sort by _row_ in Excel?

Comment: I only know `ALT` + `D` + `S` which sorts by _row_, and prompts the user to enter a _column_ on which to sort.

Comment: This answer is simpler so I am giving this as correct answer. @pnuts please just mention that for sorting you have click on options and change orientation to make it a completely descriptive answer.

Comment: yeah, alright but I really don't want to delete this question,as there were no direct question on this(as far as I searched). I will update my question for completing above purpose using VBA script (too) for complex data with Missing value etc. I guess that will make it more of a programming question.

Comment: My last try, else i will delete the question myself or migrate it to Super User

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an addendum to the response given by @pnuts, which, if possible to use, is far simpler.  If you cannot sort by column for some reason, one way to achieve your result is to take the transpose of the input (i.e. swap rows and columns), sort alphabetically by *row*, then transpose back to get the original format.  Here is a step by step guide for how to do this:

[image]

Highlight a `4x3` region of the spreadsheet where you want the transposed data to go.  Then enter a transpose array formula, which is `=TRANSPOSE($A$1:$D$3)` in the example above.  Note carefully that the cell ranges are absolute (`$`) so that it doesn't change as Excels copies it over the range.  Also remember to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, to tell Excel that you are entering an array formula.  Next copy this data to a new location (values only), and sort in descending order by the letter column:

[image]

The final step is to take the transpose of this sorted data to obtain your final result:

[image]

Again, this involved using the `TRANSPOSE` function with an array formula.

Now you have your original data sorted by column.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. Insert a top row for dummy purpose with values 1, 2, 3, 4
2. Copy all data including this dummy row -> paste special -> transpose in some other location
3. Sort the transposed data using "Largest to smallest" with "Expand" option
4. Now again copy the data, this time without the first dummy column -> paste special -> transpose.

Phew...

Picture attached. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the Cells you want to sort. Right Click on them, choose `Sort` -> `Custom Sort`

Click on Options and choose `Left to Right`. And set the settings as in the picture:

[image]

And press Ok.